# LSTMs: BPTT vs RTRL in training

Tags: backpropagation, lstm

In the [2000 paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.5709) that originally described the modern LSTM (Gers et al.), the training algorithm is described as follows:

> Output units use BPTT; output gates use slightly, modified, truncated BPTT. Weights to cells, input gates, and the novel forget gates, however, use a truncated version of RTRL.

However this choice is not justified in the text.

Is there an intuitive explanation for the decision of training output gates with BPTT and the other gates with RTRL?